# Bash vi mode - bind "C-c" to escape from insert mode

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I just discover the magic of using vi style in bash. Immediately, I'm trying to use C-c to escape from insert mode (into what's called movement mode) as I'm used to C-c to escape to command mode in vim.

I searched around and found the command to rebind key in bash:

```
"bind -m vi-insert C-c:vi-movement-mode"
```

Then, I used "bind -P" to check the binding status and it showed:

```
"..."
"vi-movement-mode can be found on "\C-c", "\e"."
```

However, when I tried to escape from insert mode, it cleared the entire line instead (the default behavior), instead of escape to movement mode... Any thought how can I use C-c to escape from insert mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for showing me that bash vi mode exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebind the interrupt key:

```
stty intr ^X
```

Now to interrupt something that's executing you'll have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>. I don't know if changing this might have other side effects.

The reason that vim can do that is that it traps the Ctrl-c interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the old trick to map the Caps Lock to ESC:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```

Which basically resembles how keyboards used to work once.